# Sequelize: Foreign key declared, but does not appear in the table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to using `Sequelize` and for that I strictly follow the documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html). It is written that we must use `hasOne()`, `hasMany()`, `belongsTo()` in order to add automatically the foreign keys. In my situation: I have a *Category* and a *FAQ* model, defined so:

**Category.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/connection');

const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    categoryShop_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    parent_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

Category.associate = (models) => {
    Category.hasMany(models.faqs, {
        onDelete:'CASCADE',
        onUpdate:'CASCADE'
    });
};

module.exports = Category;
```

**Faq.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/connection');

const Faq = sequelize.define('Faq', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    question: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    answer: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    product_id: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: true
    }
});

Faq.associate = (models) => {
    Faq.belongsTo(models.categories, {
        foreignKey: {
            name: 'category_id',
            allowNull: true
        }
    });
};

module.exports = Faq;
```

The migrations run without any errors, but I don't see the added columns to the table. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusing model and migration code. Your migrations are ok, but lack the right foreign key columns for your associations.

Your association code looks ok but it belongs in your model.

Look at https://sequelizeui.app/ for some example code.

Comment: No, the whole code is in the model. Should the association be in the migration when creating the table?